# Does Lambda continue works after timeOut ERROR?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, timeout

I have a `Lambda` function which sometimes gets a timeOut ERROR. I want to know does `Lambda` finish event loop tasks after the timeOut ERROR or does it fail and do nothing? It looks like, `Lambda` fails after timeOut ERROR and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they terminate when the timeout is reached.

> When the specified timeout is reached, AWS Lambda terminates execution of your Lambda function.

And for completeness:

> The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The default is 3 seconds. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds.

**References**

[AWS Lambda enables functions that can run up to 15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/)

[AWS Lambda Function Configuration - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html)